# How to properly handle a circular module dependency in Python?

Tags: python, module, importerror, cyclic-reference, cyclic-dependency

Trying to find a good and proper pattern to handle a circular module dependency in Python.  Usually, the solution is to remove it (through refactoring); however, in this particular case we would really like to have the functionality that requires the circular import.

**EDIT**: According to answers below, the usual angle of attack for this kind of issue would be a refactor.  However, for the sake of this question, assume that is not an option (for whatever reason).

**The problem:**

The `logging` module requires the `configuration` module for some of its configuration data.  However, for some of the `configuration` functions I would really like to use the custom logging functions that are defined in the `logging` module.  Obviously, importing the `logging` module in `configuration` raises an error.

**The possible solutions we can think of:**

1. **Don't do it**.  As I said before, this is not a good option, unless all other possibilities are ugly and bad.
2. **Monkey-patch the module**.  This doesn't sound too bad: load the `logging` module dynamically into `configuration` *after* the initial import, and before any of its functions are actually used.  This implies defining global, per-module variables, though.
3. **Dependency injection**.  I've read and run into dependency injection alternatives (particularly in  the Java Enterprise space) and they remove some of this headache; however, they may be too complicated to use and manage, which is something we'd like to avoid.  I'm not aware of how the panorama is about this in Python, though.

What is a good way to enable this functionality?

Thanks very much!

Comment: put the shared bits in its own (3rd)file and import it into both other files

Comment: would it work to put the import in an `if True:` statement?

Comment: @JoranBeasley That is the most popular answer.  It is very, very likely that this is what we'll end up doing.  Thanks.

Comment: @jcfollower Yes, probably.  That is kind of a monkey-patch, isn't it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said, there's probably some refactoring needed. According to the names, it might be ok if a logging modules uses configuration, when thinking about what things should be in configuration one think about configuration parameters, then a question arises, why is that configuration logging at all?

Chances are that the parts of the code under configuration that uses logging does not belong to the configuration module: seems like it is doing some kind of processing and logging either results or errors.

Without inner knowledge, and using only common sense, a "configuration" module should be something simple without much processing and it should be a leaf in the import tree.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I agree.  However, I am kind of asking this in a "assume this is not possible" way, to determine possible alternatives.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto: It is never "not possible" technically. The only "not possible" scenarios are either you don't want to do it or you boss doesn't want to do it

Comment: @slebetman Right - but sometimes it's about tradeoffs. If there is a simple solution that makes the code more readable or if there is a way that will improve maintainability, it might be good to implement.  In any case, the main purpose of this question is to get the opinions of informed, experienced developers, who will most likely have awesome things to say.  For example, I consider it interesting that no one has yet suggested a dependency injection solution - something I did not expect.  Thanks for your input, though; I wholeheartedly agree with the "it's never not possible" statement.

Answer (score 3):

Will this work for you?

```
# MODULE a (file a.py)
import b
HELLO = "Hello"

# MODULE b (file b.py)
try:
    import a
    # All the code for b goes here, for example:
    print("b done",a.HELLO))
except:
    if hasattr(a,'HELLO'):
        raise
    else:
        pass
```

Now I can do an import b.  When the circular import (caused by the import b statement in a) throws an exception, it gets caught and discarded.  Of course your entire module b will have to indented one extra block spacing, and you have to have inside knowledge of where the variable HELLO is declared in a.

If you don't want to modify b.py by inserting the try:except: logic, you can move the whole b source to a new file, call it c.py, and make a simple file b.py like this:

```
# new Module b.py
try:
    from c import *
    print("b done",a.HELLO) 
except:
    if hasattr(a,"HELLO"):
        raise
    else:
        pass

# The c.py file is now a copy of b.py:
import a
# All the code from the original b, for example:
print("b done",a.HELLO))
```

This will import the entire namespace from c to b, and paper over the circular import as well.

I realize this is gross, so don't tell anyone about it.

Comment: OK, so this essentially looks like a case of monkey-patching.  There is a similar version of this that could work - however, I'm not sure that's what _should_ be done.  Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is monkey-patching. It looks like the pattern used in C++ which is to say "If a module is not defined yet, define it here, if it has, skip". There are still situations that will produce an infinite loop though where it keeps bouncing back and forth among the files in a circular dependency. The way this was sometimes alleviated was to declare that the functions existed in a file separate from the function definitions (The C++ header, .h and code, .cpp files)

Answer (score 2):

A cyclic module dependency is usually a code smell.

It indicates that part of the code should be re-factored so that it is external to both modules.

Comment: Agree.  However, I am curious about how it could be solved, if it were determined that refactoring to avoid it would not be the ideal thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

So if I'm reading your use case right, `logging` accesses `configuration` to get configuration data. However, `configuration` has some functions that, when called, require that stuff from `logging` be imported in `configuration`.

If that is the case (that is, `configuration` doesn't really need `logging` until you start calling functions), the answer is simple: in `configuration`, place all the imports from `logging` at the bottom of the file, after all the class, function and constant definitions.

Python reads things from top to bottom: when it comes across an `import` statement in `configuration`, it runs it, but at this point, `configuration` already exists as a module that can be imported, even if it's not fully initialized yet: it only has the attributes that were declared before the `import` statement was run.

I do agree with the others though, that circular imports are usually a code smell.

Comment: Interesting :).  I'll check this out.  Yep, I agree with the refactoring idea as well, but it is interesting to have a good overview of possible alternatives… sometimes doing a refactor might not be worth it or could potentially make it less understandable. +1